# Media queries: How to NOT target Ipad

Tags: css, media-queries, landscape-portrait

I know there is a lot of topics out there about media queries, but tonight I'm stuck on this:

I'm targeting many Smartphones and specifically Samsung Galaxy S3 with this :

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 720px), (min-device-width: 721px) { .. }
```

it works well for both portrtait and landscape! But I don't know why, in this way I am also targeting **Ipad landscape mode**, which I don't want to! In case I'd rather prefer to target portrait view of Ipad together with smartphones!
To be clear, what I want to achieve is to have 2 versions of a website, default is a layout of max-width 960px and a smaller version that is very good for Smartphones and good for Ipad and other tablets on portrait.. Now the mobile version is working on smartphones but to little on Ipad...

I know that I could target Ipad directly, but I don't want to replicate many css rules that would be the same of desktop!

Comment: You should‘t use media queries to detect hardware vendors.

Comment: You might want to change your title to "How to NOT target iPad". The current title seems to mean you're asking for disrecommended techniques.

Comment: I guess you are right David. @Jongsma I would but I can't change it! Anyway I changed approach and I'm using server side detection mobile_detect.php in conjuction with media queries. I'm testing to see which is the best use of it and if more than 3 PHP queries are too much on the same page to exclude blocks of content: if($detect->isMobile())

Comment: Changed it for you. Coming from an irrelevant google search, I thought this could be the title of a funny code-related article. Turns out nope. #edit Oh wow this is old.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the syntax of your media query. You've used a comma instead of `and` and I think you have max/min around the wrong way. For CSS Media Queries a `,` is the OR separator whereas `AND` requires multiple queries to be true.

Your media query should instead look like:

`@media screen and (min-device-width: 720px) and (max-device-width: 721px) { .. }`

Or written more succinctly you could use the specific `device-width`:

`@media screen and (device-width: 720px) { .. }`

Using this method you could target Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape by using the comma, ie:

`@media screen and (device-width: 720px), (device-width: 1280px) { .. }`